# mod, div in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

```
main = do
    let a = 50
    let y = 7
    let area = (a ** y) 
    print (area)   
    print (a `mod` y)
```

I expected it to print:

```
781250000000   -- 50 to the 7th power
1              -- remainder of 50/7
```

But instead I get a series of ambiguous type errors like this:

```
test.hs:2:13:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `50'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thanks for including a small, self-contained test case -- it makes everything easier! (upvoted!). I updated the question with actual and expected values to make it even easier to diagnose.

Comment: Note that function calls do not need parentheses. You can write `print area` and `print $ a `mod` y`. The second one is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 9):

Simple; take a look at the types of `(**)` and `mod`:

```
Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t mod
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

It is a rare numeric type that has *both* the characteristics of an integer *and* the characteristics of a floating-point number. You have a couple of choices for dealing with this:

1. Use an exponentiation operation that handles integer-like numbers well. For example, `(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a`.
2. Use a modulus operation that handles floating-point numbers well. For example, `mod' :: Real a => a -> a -> a`.
3. Explicitly convert to a floating-point type with `realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b` before calling `(**)`.
4. Explicitly convert to an integer-like type with `floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b` (or another rounding function) before calling `mod`.